# [ RESOLVIDO ]Não estou conseguindo buscar um categoria do banco pelo ID

Tags: java, mysql, rest, restful, postman

Não está retornando nenhum erro console da IDE e nem no Postman.

Classe DAO

```
public static Categorias pesquisar(int idCategorias) throws Exception {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CATEGORIAS WHERE idCategorias = ?";

        try (PreparedStatement ps = DB.connect().prepareStatement(sql)) {

            ps.setInt(1, idCategorias);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                Categorias categorias = new Categorias();
                
                categorias.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                categorias.setIdCategorias(rs.getInt("idCategorias"));
                

                return categorias;
            }else {
                return null;
            }

        } 
        
    }


Classe de serviço 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("pesquisarId")
    public Categorias pesquisarId(@QueryParam("idCategorias") int idCategorias) {

        try {
            DaoCategorias.pesquisar(idCategorias);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: já fez debug pra conferir seu a query está ok, se retorna algo?

Comment: Poste a exceção, por favor! Auxiliará a identificar se o erro está na estrutura da tabela no banco de dados.

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento , no console do eclipse não retorna nenhuma exceção e no postman também não aparece nenhum erro.

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou conferir, vlw pela dica !

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu fiz o debug e ele está pegando o id consultado normalmente, coloquei uns prints pegando id e nome e ele aparece no console, só que no postman n retorna nada

Comment: Arilson, a área de respostas deve ser usada apenas para responder a pergunta, não use para adicionar detalhes. Para isso clique em"Editar" e adicione diretamente a pergunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo aqui, você não está salvando o retorno do seu método estático

> DaoCategorias.pesquisar(idCategorias)

ou seja, o resultado da sua query do banco de dados é perdido. Conforme segue:

```
    try {
        DaoCategorias.pesquisar(idCategorias);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Não é necessário salvar o retorno em uma variável, você pode apenas retorna-la, conforme abaixo:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("pesquisarId")
public Categorias pesquisarId(int idCategorias) throws Exception {
    try {
        return DaoCategorias.pesquisar(idCategorias);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Acho que com isso você já consegue ver alguma coisa, mas eu diria para investir um tempo tentando deixar o seu código melhor estruturado, isto é, facilitar a validação/teste, leitura e fluxo lógico, esses pontos já vão facilitar muito o seu desenvolvimento e debug.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, com o retorno desta forma deu certo, muito obrigado mesmo pessoal !!

Comment: Legal, marca a minha resposta como aceita para fechar a perguntar e me dar uns pontinhos =D